# Replacing an elements innerHTML with a copy of itself changes the document height?

Tags: javascript, html, objective-c

I'm trying to fix a bug in my iOS app. I've tracked it down to some Javascript that I'm running in a webView.

When I do the following:

```
 var innerHTML = anElement.innerHTML;

//in the full code I do other things here
//but the issue remains even with nothing here

 anElement.innerHTML = innerHTML;
```

occasionally the document height at the beginning and the end of the code snippet above are not the same; the document gets smaller, by a few pixels.

Can someone explain why this might be happening?

Comment: in the comments section "in the full code I do other things here" are you playing with dom elements like removing some element or changing style of an element or something of that kind?

Comment: I wrap a range of the text in the element in a span, then find the boundingClientRect of that span. Then I try to use the second line in the code I posted above to undo any changes made to the dom. However the issue is still there when there is NOTHING where I have the comment  (I only put the comment there so no one asked why I am doing the other two lines of code)

Comment: Have you identified what exactly is getting smaller?  If you can narrow it down to a specific element maybe you can find some css rules behaving strangely.

Comment: @IrkenInvader good idea, thanks. Having a quick look at it, it seems that possibly some fonts are changing size in the rest of the document prior to the element that the code is dealing with and not that element itself. Very strange.  All fonts are sized inline from a style property on the body element, because that way is easier to deal with from within the app. This should mean that the fonts should be the same size throughout the document (?) but after the above code, fonts seem slightly smaller at the beginning than at the end. Weird. Still, it's a clue!

Comment: Quick update: I've noticed that this issue only happens on actual devices, and not in the iPhone simulator, which makes me think it is possibly a bug. And also  (thanks to @IrkenInvader) I had the idea of setting every "p" elements fontSize to 100%, which seems to be getting rid of the original issue. Although I am not very happy with it as a solution, and it is causing a few other issues, but it is a bit of progress  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Appears to be fixed by adding CSS:

```
html {
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: none; /* Never autoresize text */
}
```

or in the obj-c apply it to each page with:

```
NSString* jsString =  @"var style = document.createElement(\"style\"); document.head.appendChild(style); style.innerHTML = \"html{-webkit-text-size-adjust: none;}\"";
[self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsString]
```

(This is obviously for a UIWebView, and I also need to write some code to make sure it is not added twice)